# multiplication inside an input with "*" operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am trying to get a multiplication entered in an `input` replaced by its solution.

Basicaly, when you enter `3*3` into the `input`, I would like my javascript code to replace `3*3` by `9`.

Probably not so hard to obtain but I'm a total noob with javascript here. I get this so far, but I should miss a crucial point!

Thanks for your help :)

```js
function multiply() {
  var string = document.getElementById("mult").value;
  var array = string.split("*");
  var res = Number(array[0]*array[1]);
  document.getElementById("res").value = res;
}
```

```css
input{width:80px; text-align:right;}
input[readonly]{border:0;}
```

```html
entrer: <input type="text" id="mult" onblur="multiply()">
<br>result: <input type="text" id="res" readonly>
```

Comment: what about `document.getElementById("mult").value = res;`

Comment: Your code works for me in the snippet. I typed in "3*3" and when I clicked outside the box the result showed as 9.

Comment: Yep, it was actually a working code I wasn't able to make working yesterday. don't know what happened!
And @Tareq, you're right, that's where I wanted to end!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually works as it is now. Just make sure you tab out of the input field after typing in the equation and you'll see it do its job. That's because your code is running on the `blur` event, which is when the focus leaves an element.

But, as far as your conversion code goes:

```
Number(array[0]*array[1])
```

Attempts to convert the product of `array[0]` and `array[1]`, when what you need is to convert each array value to a number first and then do the math.

```
Number(array[0]) * Number(array[1])
```

Now, instead of `Number()`, you can just prepend a `+` to each value that needs conversion.

```
+array[0] * +array[1]
```

But, in reality, anytime you attempt to do multiplication, division or subtraction on strings, they are automatically converted to numbers, so you really don't even need that here.

Lastly, since you are just displaying the result and don't want the user to be able to modify it, just put it into a regular element, like a `span` instead of a form field element that you then have to set to `readonly`. Form fields are primarily for collecting information, not displaying it. When you do work with a non-form field element, you don't use the `value` property, you use `.textContent` (when there is straight text) or `.innerHTML` (when the string contains HTML to be parsed).

```js
function multiply() {
  var string = document.getElementById("mult").value;
  var array = string.split("*");
  var res = array[0] * array[1];
  document.getElementById("res").textContent = res;
}
```

```css
input{width:80px; text-align:right;}
input[readonly]{border:0;}
```

```html
entrer: <input type="text" id="mult" onblur="multiply()">
<br>result: <span id="res"></span>
```

Comment: I can't understand why it didn't seem to work yesterday :/

Anyway, thanks for your advices!